# Navigation Drawer using Navigation View vs Recycler View

Tags: android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I am creating an app which should have navigation drawer.
I want to know the difference between creating **navigation drawer using recycler view** and **navigation activity provided in android studio**.

Which one should I use?

Comment: You're not going to get many answers if you're already making demands what the answer should contain.

Comment: @JamesZ  i didn't understand your point, actually I was assigned a task to create a menu list divider in the navigation drawer and the TL suggested to create navigation using recycler view, but I achieved the task with some other method in default Navigation drawer and it works fine, then what difference could it have made if I went with the approach of using RecyclerView to make Navigation drawer.
Just not this, I want to know every difference in functional aspect of both approaches.